# How to alter headers to download a file in WordPress when headers are already being sent out in a previous file?

Tags: php, wordpress, header

On one of our wordPress pages, we would like to download a file through the browser. As far as I know, this is done by modifying the header so the page believes that it's a certain type of file (.txt for example). However, both the theme, along with dozens of plugins load prior to this page loading and many of them are outputting some sort of data, or modifying the header in some way that I'm constantly getting the infamous header error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/keep/public_html/wp-content/themes/procyon/header.php:2) in
>   /home/keep/public_html/wp-content/themes/procyon/functions.php on line
>   97

So, how can I possibly get around the fact that other plugins are modifying header information before I would like to? Surely there must be *some* way as other plugins are not having this problem with one another.

For those of you who appreciate seeing some sort of effort, here is the code that I am using:

```
$tmp_handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');

foreach ($arr as $fields) {
    fputcsv($tmp_handle, $fields);
}

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyVerySpecial.csv');
rewind($tmp_handle);

echo stream_get_contents($tmp_handle);
```

I would really appreciate some help on this matter, thank you!

Comment: Hi there ! Have you found a solution for that ? i've got the same problem :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is make the user download something then you don't need to use the templating system. You know for sure that nothing has been output before "template_redirect" so you can use this fact to write something like this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'download_page');
function download_page() {
    if($_GET['download'] == 'true') {
        //Output header information and the file content
        exit; // Stops Wordpress from executing anything else.
    }
}
```

Now perhaps you do need the templating system to deliver the file, I don't know, but your description does not specifically state that.

Comment: Unfortunately, WordPress won't let me add a function like that. It's telling me "unexpected function..."

Comment: Sorry, you probably have a PHP version lower than 5.3 (which is when anonymous functions were introduced). This is easily resolved by creating a named dummy function. I updated the example, I should've written it that way to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Break it out of Wordpress. You'll have to upload a new file such as `headers.php` and link to it from Wordpress.

Comment: That's the kind of thinking I was looking for, thanks! I'll go try it out and let you know how I fare.

Comment: EDIT - that didn't even work, uploaded another PHP file to the remote server, called it from the wordpress page.

Comment: And your filename should be like: `filename="MyVerySpecial.csv"`

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error. And I will change the file name but I have a feeling it works either way. Regardless, yes, I'm having the same headers error.

Comment: `but I have a feeling it works either way` you could be right. that's not causing this error, but I thought I'd throw it out there. When you say your calling it from wordpress, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7062/discussion-between-evan-and-paul)

Comment: thanks for talking with me but now that I think about it, the function *was* being done through a separate PHP file, I was only doing the *calling* through the WordPress page. So, I'm afraid that I'm still out of ideas here.